# Using Excel2LaTeX in Excel 2010

Tags: installing, conversion, tools, excel2latex

I just installed Excel2LaTeX in Excel 2010.

I do see it in add-ins. However, I cannot find a way to operate it. That is, there is no change in the ribbon area after the package was installed.

How does one use the package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: This is really off-topic here, since your problem is with Excel and an add-in, and not with TeX itself.

Comment: @Alan: Conversion tools are usually on-topic.

Comment: I second Caramdir: "If you have a question about [...] (La)TeX related software and tools like BibTeX, LyX, LaTeX editors, viewers, and **converters** ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!" [(FAQ)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: It does NOT work in Excel 2011 for Mac. For 2010 and 2007 I had to restart to see the ribbon. Microsoft is hopeless.

Answer (score 29):

After an add-in has been installed, it is available to use, but it has to be activated first. For this, follow [these](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-or-disable-add-ins-in-office-programs-HA010034127.aspx) instructions. An abbreviated list of steps are:

1. Click the **Microsoft Office Button**.
2. Click **Excel Options**.
3. Click **Add-Ins**.
4. Note the Add-in **Type** in the list displayed.
5. Select the Add-in **Type** in the manage box and click **Go**.
6. Select [clear] the check box for the Add-in that you want enable [disable] and then click **OK**.

Specifically for the [Excel2LaTeX add-in for Excel](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/), after downloading it and reaching step 5 above, this is how I installed it on my computer:

- Locating the Excel2LaTeX add-in by clicking on the *Browse* button:

[image: Locating the Excel2LaTeX add-in]

- Activating the Excel2LaTeX add-in by selecting it from the add-in menu:

[image: Activating the Excel2LaTeX add-in]

- New add-in menu showing the "Convert to LaTeX table" button in Excel:

[image: New add-in menu showing the "Convert to LaTeX table" button in Excel]

Note that any add-in is specific to the location that it is stored in, since the code/macros are stored in a file rather than being "installed" under your traditional "Program Files" folder. So, it would be preferable to put it in a recognizable folder that you can find and access later. That is, avoid putting it in something like `C:\Temp\` where it may be easily erased.

Comment: I did activate it.
However, there is no new buttom that allows me to copy a table into LaTex.

Comment: @Slava: I've updated my answer to show what I did to get it installed on my computer. I did this in Excel 2007. However, the CTAN link I provided suggests v3.1 (as of May 19, 2011) of the Add-in works for Excel 2007+. Perhaps you have an older version that may not be compatible.

Comment: after restarting excel, the button should be there.
Thankts for the instructions, for me it works!

Comment: Will the add-on also extract the graphs from the excel file or only data?

Answer (score 10):

Use this online version instead! No installation necessary.

http://ericwood.org/excel2latex/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: That tool is pretty buggy, and doesn't convert things like merged cells.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Excel 2013 and did initially not manage to get Excel2LaTeX to show in add-ins, it seems to work for some people and not for others using the same version of Excel. What worked for me was to disable all other add-ins that were listed before Excel2LaTeX . When I did that Excel2LaTeX showed upp in add-ins and works! [image: Try disabling other add-Ins]

Answer (score 0):

Although, the question is for Excel 2010, I think Excel 2020 is also relevant here.

I have to do 2 extra steps to make it working in excel 2020.

1. Unblock the xla file by going to properties and check the unblock as highlighted in the picture.

[image]

2. After unblocking open the file and try to run excel2latex functions by going to Add in tab. A pop up will appear asking to allow macros. Allow them and everything will work.