# Using external tables in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, external-files

How do I use tabela.xls as a data source to a LaTeX table or even a table made with TikZ with the following command?
Note: I wanted to use tabela.xls as a data source for multiple files. Tex and that it is synchronized when I change the tabela.xls.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}] at (0,0)
      {
    1 & Knuth &         10\\
    2 & Lamport &  10\\
    3 & Mittelbach & 7\\
    4 & Oetiker &   7\\
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is possible from within LaTeX. However, there's an Excel2LaTeX add-on for Excel that formats an Excel table for LaTeX use. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/using-excel2latex-in-excel-2010

Comment: IMHO I don't like `xls` or other OLE 2 Compound Document format. If you want to automate your table generation, I strongly suggest you to export the `xls` spreadsheet to a `csv` format and then read it in LaTeX using the [`datatool`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool.pdf) package. I have no idea how to integrate `datatool` with `TikZ`. `:-(`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way of a direct use of `xls` files in LaTeX, more precisely the `OLE 2 Compound Document` format, which is in binary form.

From 2007 on, Microsoft Excel uses `Office Open XML` for their new `xlsx` format, based on `XML`. But I don't believe it would be easier to parse it from LaTeX. **Update:** format is zipped, so binary again.

My suggestion is to use an easier format, say, comma-separated values. `cvs` is a plain text format. Excel can easily export a spreadsheet to `csv`.

We have the [`datatool`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool.pdf) package which handles `csv` files and might help you to populate your table. I'm not sure how it would work with `TikZ`.

[Joseph](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2098622#2098622) also suggested me that `pdfplotstable` might help with displaying the data.

If you do want to stick with `xls` files, Werner's suggestion is the way to go.

Hope it helps. `:-)`

**Update:** Here's an example with a plain and simple table:

[image: LibreOffice]

When saving it, I can choose the `csv` format:

[image: CSV format]

Which will give me the following plain text (`scores.csv`):

```
ID,Name,Score
1,Knuth,10
2,Lamport,10
3,Mittelbach,7
4,Oetiker,7
```

Now, in LaTeX with `datatool`:

`ex1.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[keys={ID,Name,Score}]{scores}{scores.csv}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Our final score}
\centering
\DTLdisplaydb{scores}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`ex2.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLloaddb[keys={ID,Name,Score}]{scores}{scores.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Our final score}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{clr}
\textbf{ID} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Score}
\DTLforeach{scores}{%
\id=ID,\name=Name,\score=Score}{%
\\ \id & \name & \score}     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Table]

(I don't know how to do that with `TikZ`, sorry.)

There's a follow-up to this question: [Can luaLaTeX convert xlsx tables into LaTeX code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30654/can-lualatex-convert-xlsx-tables-into-latex-code). With LuaLatex, it might be possible to unzip the file and extract data from the resulting XML. Not so easy though, IMHO.

Comment: Datatool is good idea. I will test. Thanks.

Comment: Show me example, please.

Answer (score 9):

With [`pgfplotstable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) (which is part of `pgfplots`) you can do something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    columns/Name/.style={string type},
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule}
    ]{scores.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ignasi! Now I learned a new way of displaying `csv` data. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

For a different way of doing this, if you really need to import data in some sort of binary format, like `xls`, and especially if you want to do some calculation with the data, you could use [`R`](http://www.r-project.org/) with [`Sweave`](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/).  The `R` statistical software can read number of [formats](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import) using the `gdata` library, and `Sweave` lets you incorporate `R` code into `latex` file.  Assuming you have a file `data.xls` that looks like this:

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

You would create a file `report.Rnw` with this content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}
<<echo=false, results=hide>>=
library(xtable)
library(gdata)
data <- read.xls("data.xls")
@
Table~\ref{tab:mydata} shows my data.
<<echo=false, results=tex>>=
print(xtable(data, caption = "My data", label="tab:mydata"))
@
\end{document}
```

As you see, it is a regular LaTeX file with pieces if `R` code delimited by 
`<<options>>` and `@` on separate lines.  You would then run `Sweave` on it like so:

```
R CMD Sweave report.Rnw
```

That would produce a `report.tex` file.  Running LaTeX on the file would then typeset the following:

[image: resulting table]

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a post with video tutorial on how to use Excel for tables in Latex. Hope you will find it useful: http://quicklatex.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-create-table-in-latex-from-ms.html

The first method - suing datatool package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb[keys={c1,c2,c3}]{ctext}{csvtext.csv}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{clr}
\textbf{Software} & \textbf{Manufacturer} & \textbf{Malware}
\DTLforeach{ctext}{
\cola=c1,\colb=c2,\colc=c3}{\\
\cola & \colb & \colc}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The second method - using pgfplotstable package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep=comma,
columns/Software/.style={string type},
columns/num1/.style={string type},
columns/num2/.style={string type},
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,
after row =\midrule
},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{csvtext.csv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please expand on this to make it a full answer. When possible, answers here should be self contained or point to other questions and answers on TeX.sx.