# How to display a specific entry from an external data source input?

Tags: tables, database

I have a `data.txt` file and it contains an array of numbers, I included it in the preamble of the .tex file, now I would like to display some specific entry from the data file, not the whole data set but just some of them, how should I do?

Comment: There is no way to do this exactly as you describe, but there are various ways to deal with data of this sort.  See [Using external tables in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30589/2693) or [File input and output](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2375/2693) or [Formatting complex table from CSV using datatool](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17618/2693) for some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the PGFplotstable package, which is part of PGFplots, for this.

The data would be loaded into a table macro using `\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\datatable` (there are various options for accommodating different data file variants), after which you can access an individual element using `\pgfplotstablegetelem{<row>}{<column>}\of\datatable`. The element will then be available as `\pgfplotsretval`.