# Using Excel2LaTeX in Excel 2013

Tags: conversion, tools, excel2latex

I'm using Excel 2013 and having no luck getting the Excel2LaTeX add-in to do my bidding.

When I view my add-ins from the options menu, all seems well--Excel2LaTeX shows up, and its checkbox is marked when I go to "Manage Add-Ins".

However, there is nothing on the tool bar: no Add-Ins Ribbon, no shortcut buttons to be found under any existing headings--it's like it disappeared!!

Anyone able to figure out what's going on?

Comment: See also this very similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/using-excel2latex-in-excel-2010

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `readme` file of `Excel2LaTeX`:

> INSTALLATION ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Just open the file Excel2LaTeX.xla in Excel.
>   Then you will have two additional  menu items in your "Tools" menu and
>   a new toolbar with two buttons on it.  For  Excel 2007 and later, you
>   will have two new buttons in the "Add-Ins" ribbon.  If  you plan to
>   use the program frequently, you can save it in your addin directory 
>   and add it with Tools/Add-in.  This way it will be loaded whenever
>   Excel is  opened.

The addin directory maps to `C:\Users\Anupama\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns` for me. You have to replace `Anupama` by your user name though.

Following works for me:

Double click on `Excel2LaTeX.xla`. Excel opens it with a warning:

[image]

Click on  <kbd>Enable Macros</kbd> . You will get `ADDD-INS` like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for not deleting the answer. It was helpful.

Comment: it does not work. Nothing shows up in my add in :(

Comment: @AtenaNguyen: Can you give some more details please? Which word version do you use? Have you copied the `Excel2LaTeX.xla` in the `AddIns` directory? What about the security settings in word?

Comment: Any idea what to do if no warning shows up upon double-clicking on `Excel2LaTeX.xla`? I open it...it opens ok...I click on `AddIns`, I see the two Excel2LaTeX icons, I click on one of them and receive an error that Excel2LaTeX has been moved.