# Alternatives for excel2latex working on office 2016?

Tags: excel2latex

It's not working on the newest office 2016. Is there any other macro can do this? Or I need to download an older version of Office.

[image: The error]

Comment: I won't call it a duplicate but related: [Using Excel2LaTeX in Excel 2010](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24897/28808).  The question is about running it for the first time, which may be equivalent if you've just upgraded.  Otherwise we need more information to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @ChrisH apparently both double-click and option-add-in will call an error when Excel launch saying: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: That needs debugging by someone with the same version and some knowledge of VBA.  I have the latter but not the former (and to be perfectly honest little interest in getting it).

Comment: @ChrisH I see. Then can you suggest me some alternative ways to process data and get them into LaTeX table?

Comment: Honestly, not really, it's not something I've really done.  But you could have a look at [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) and [datatool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) (via csv files) for 2 very different approaches